# Ansible to SUBST a drive machine-wide

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, subst

I've set up Ansible to connect to a Windows Server 2019 using WinRM certificate method. I need to  map D drive to simply mirror C. With SUBST I can do `SUBST D: C:\` but...

- When I run the command with Ansible using `win_shell` Remote Desktop does not show the drive.
- The opposite is also true: when I run the command with Remote Desktop, Ansible's shell does not see the new D drive.
- I tried using [registry tricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUBST) to make the mapping persist, and after rebooting I can see the drive in File Explorer with Remote Desktop but neither PowerShell nor Ansible's `win_shell` see it.

How can I map C to D machine-wide using an Ansible playbook?

Comment: When you defined the "D:" drive link in "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices", did you target the volume device "\??\C:" or the root directory "\??\C:\"? It should be the volume device for maximum compatibility; subst.exe can't do that. For added measure, I'd also make it an explicitly global device path, e.g. "\GLOBAL??\C:".

Comment: Bear in mind however, that this is not a canonical drive registered with the mountpoint manager, so API functions such as `GetFinalPathNameByHandleW` will still resolve to the "C:" drive.

Comment: @ErykSun I was missing the `\??\` prefix. Thanks for the useful comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry value for the drive was missing `\??\` prefix. Everything works correctly with the right registry value. For the record, this is the ansible task I ended up with:

```
    - name: Map D drive to C.
      ansible.windows.win_regedit:
        path: HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices
        name: "D:"
        state: present
        type: string
        data: '\??\C:'
```

Comment: Target "\??\C:" or "\Global??\C:" for the best result, not the root directory "\??\C:\". Some API functions are buggy if a drive is actually a directory instead of a device -- e.g. `GetVolumePathNameW` misbehaves badly for subst.exe drives since they target a directory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to do that, but you can try to use workstation service :

```
Net use d: \\localhost\c$
```

One problem you may encouter is that the command has to be run by the same user who use it, for example, if you run it in an elevated administrator shell, you won't see it in a simple user shell.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't work exactly for the needs of a legacy system I'm working with, but it may well be useful to somebody visiting this page.